# Microsoft Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, linear-regression

I built an ML linear regression model. 
[trainning_exp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KdRz.png)[score_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkm7V.png)
When I 'preview' in Score Model I have a lot of empty fields.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: You should replace nulls with averages or with default values

Comment: I replace missing values ​​with mean in 'Clear Missing Data'. 
It's not correct?

Comment: Correctness depends on your task specific. I can't answer to this question